# How do I get a query to return a "1" value in place of text

Tags: sql, count

Here's the full code:

```
WITH Part1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        session_id, occurred_at, activity_name
    FROM      
        Activity_Data_Table$
    WHERE   
        (occurred_at > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 31) 
        AND (activity_name = 'create')
    GROUP BY 
        session_id, occurred_at, activity_name
), 
Part2 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        session_id, occurred_at, activity_name
    FROM      
        Activity_Data_Table$ AS Activity_Data_Table$_1
    WHERE   
        (occurred_at > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 31) 
        AND (activity_name = 'Resolve')
    GROUP BY 
        session_id, occurred_at, activity_name
)
SELECT 
    Part1_1.occurred_at, Part1_1.activity_name, 
    Part2_1.activity_name
FROM   
    Part1 AS Part1_1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Part2 AS Part2_1 ON Part1_1.session_id = Part2_1.session_id
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

It returns 3 columns:

```
Date, activity 1, activity 2
```

What I want, and it can be in additional columns or substitute: in the 2 activity columns, if there is a non-null value (create or resolve) then I want to insert a '1' otherwise  0 or null.  Tried countless ways of inserting count and it's just not working, but I'm sure someone with better skills this is 2 seconds.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to query the table twice and join the results.

```
SELECT 
    session_id,
    occurred_at,
    MAX(CASE WHEN activity_name = 'create'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_create,
    MAX(CASE WHEN activity_name = 'Resolve' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_resolve
FROM
    Activity_Data_Table$
WHERE   
        occurred_at   >  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 31
    AND activity_name IN ('create', 'Resolve')
GROUP BY
    session_id,
    occurred_at
```

This will only return sessions that have at least one or other activity.  If you want to allow sessions with neither activity, just remove the `AND activity_name IN ('create', 'Resolve')`

***EDIT:***

I just realised I don't know if the two activities happen at the same time.  If they do, great, the above query works.  If they can be different, something like this may help...

```
SELECT 
    session_id,
    MIN(occurred_at)   AS occured_at_first,
    MAX(occurred_at)   AS occured_at_last,
    MAX(CASE WHEN activity_name = 'create'  THEN occurred_at END) AS occured_at_create,
    MAX(CASE WHEN activity_name = 'Resolve' THEN occurred_at END) AS occured_at_resolve,        
    MAX(CASE WHEN activity_name = 'create'  THEN  1  ELSE  0 END) AS has_create,
    MAX(CASE WHEN activity_name = 'Resolve' THEN  1  ELSE  0 END) AS has_resolve
FROM
    Activity_Data_Table$
WHERE   
    occurred_at   >  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 31
GROUP BY
    session_id
```

It depends on what you need/want.

***EDIT:***

Daily conversion rate...

```
WITH
  created_sessions AS
(
  SELECT 
    session_id,
    occurred_at,
    MAX(CASE WHEN activity_name = 'Resolve' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS has_resolve
  FROM
    Activity_Data_Table$
  WHERE   
        occurred_at   >  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 31
    AND activity_name IN ('create', 'resolve')
  GROUP BY
    session_id,
    occurred_at
  HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN activity_name = 'create'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
)
SELECT
  occurred_at,
  AVG(has_resolve) AS conversion
FROM
  created_sessions
GROUP BY
  occurred_at
ORDER BY
  occurred_at
```

Comment: Timing won't actually matter per se. A session will create before it resolves. I actually filtered your response, to not include create if it's 0. and don't need really need to see a session number it's only there to know if it was created and resolved in same session. What I'm ultimately next trying to go for is to now summarize by day and use resolve as numerator & create as denominator (per day) for a % resolved in same session.

Comment: @DataYes Can a session have a resolve activity without a create activity?  And/or how do you want to treat a session that's created on one day, resolved on the next?  Etc, etc...

Comment: no you can't have a resolve without a create (these are desk tickets). And you can absolutely have a session create one day, and resolve days/weeks later but the ticket would have a different session number when it resolved from when it was created. That was why I built into it that it had a day and session and they were on the same line. Then built the filter to eliminate those 'resolves' that didn't have a create the same day (no null creates). Resolve can be null, so then I got 'all'  creates (denom), and I only captured those resolves  from same session/day for my numerator.

Comment: MatBaile   : Overall idea here is to figure out % that create and resolve in the same session.

Comment: MatBailie, just reread your question, yes a 'SESSION" can have a resolve without a create. (just drank my coffee).  I don't care about resolves if they come from different sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement, something like

```
SELECT ...
     , CASE 
         WHEN Part1_1.activity_name IS NOT NULL
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS activity1_name_available
     , CASE 
         WHEN Part2_1.activity_name IS NOT NULL
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS activity2_name_available
  FROM ...
```

You can also combine them for example if you need a 1 if either of them is available, or when both are available:

```
SELECT ...
     , CASE 
         WHEN Part1_1.activity_name IS NOT NULL
           OR Part2_1.activity_name IS NOT NULL
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS either_available
     , CASE 
         WHEN Part1_1.activity_name IS NOT NULL
          AND Part2_1.activity_name IS NOT NULL
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS both_available
  FROM ...
```